# Weird behavior with canvas Context variable definition location causing canvas render freeze when tab is inactive

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have come across a very odd behavior that is causing issues in Chrome (only tested browser).  I have a canvas that is being used to render an audio frequency spectrum visual.  Whenever I define the CanvasRenderingContext2D variable

```
var canvasCtx;
canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

or define the ScriptProcessorNode variable

```
var scriptNode;
scriptNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
```

and the variable definition is inside any closure or function, the visualization rendering will freeze if you switch tabs, change windows, or even change the window width size.

However, I found out that if the variable definition for those two types are defined at the global scope outside all functions, the canvas will continue to render even if the page is inactive.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating the bug:
http://jsfiddle.net/K8J26/541/
(Audio may not play in JSFiddle due to cross-origin safety, so a local file may be needed)

I am wondering, why is this happening?
Does the browser hold onto the state of variables and objects that are tied to the global scope even if the page is inactive? Or is it something completely unrelated to the location of variable definition, and instead something I just completely overlooked?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you are calculating the new size and creating the gradient while the browser has not updated the size of your elements yet.

Pass the `updateScale` in a `requestAnimationFrame` call so the browser has the time to render the elements :

```js
(function initVisualizer() {
  var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
  if (!AudioContext) {
    return;
  }

  var PERCENT_HIGH_FREQ_TRIM = 0.3;
  var PERCENT_HEIGHT_OF_WITDH = 0.25;
  var SMOTHING_CONSTANT = 0.6;

  var audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  var canvas = document.getElementById("visualizer");
  canvas.style.width = "100%";

  // Defining canvasCtx here causes frozen canvas rendering when tab is inactive
  var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  // Defining scriptNode here causes frozen canvas rendering when tab is inactive
  var scriptNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);
  scriptNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = SMOTHING_CONSTANT;
  analyser.connect(scriptNode);

  var widthMax;
  var heightMax;
  var dataCount;
  var barWidth;
  var barOffset;
  var gradient;

  scriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {
    var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(dataCount);
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

    canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, widthMax, heightMax);

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = gradient;

    var modifier = heightMax / 255;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataCount; i++) {
      var value = ~~(frequencyData[i] * modifier);

      canvasCtx.fillRect(i * (barWidth + barOffset), heightMax - value, barWidth, heightMax);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    if (canvas.parentElement.offsetWidth !== widthMax) {
      requestAnimationFrame(updateScale);
    }
  });

  function updateScale() {

    widthMax = canvas.offsetWidth;
    heightMax = ~~(widthMax * PERCENT_HEIGHT_OF_WITDH);

    var size = nearestPow2(~~(widthMax / 4));
    dataCount = ~~((size / 2) * (1 - PERCENT_HIGH_FREQ_TRIM));
    var rectWidth = widthMax / dataCount;
    barOffset = rectWidth * 0.25;
    barWidth = rectWidth - barOffset;
    analyser.fftSize = size;

    canvas.setAttribute("width", widthMax);
    canvas.setAttribute("height", heightMax);

    gradient = canvasCtx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, heightMax);
    gradient.addColorStop(1, "#ff6600");
    gradient.addColorStop(0, "#ffff00");
  }

  function playAudio(audio) {
    var sourceNode = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    sourceNode.connect(analyser);
    sourceNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    console.log(audio.play());
    setTimeout(function() {
      audio.pause();
    }, 30000);
  }

  function nearestPow2(size) {
    return Math.pow(2, Math.round(Math.log(size) / Math.log(2)));
  }

  updateScale();
  playAudio(document.getElementById('audio'));
})();
```

```css
body {
  background: #222;
}
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls crossorigin="anonymous">
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg" />
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/dc/Strawberry_Fields_Forever_%28Beatles_song_-_sample%29.ogg" />
</audio>
<canvas id="visualizer"></canvas>
```

However I don't know why it was working when you set the variable in global context...

Ps : your fiddle wasn't working on FF and only worked on chrome because of a bug, you need to set the `crossorigin` attribute before the resource are loaded, otherwise it has no effect.

Comment: I don't think the resizing or scaling was the problem because the rendering (scriptNode.onaudioprocess) still freezes if the tab is inactive, and the variables are defined within the closure.  I updated the JSFiddle link using your updates, so if you switch tabs or change windows and wait while the audio is playing and come back, you will see that the canvas is frozen. That is the weird problem I have. the resizing is an issue in the same way changing tabs or windows is.

Comment: @JonMcPherson then I can't reproduce your issue, the only one I had was because of this resizing, and that crossOrigin thing